# No reputation awarded for a suggested edit

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I am editing questions for better understanding. However, for an approved edit, I get 2 Reputation points. On Rejection, I get 0 points, with reason. Recently, I have successfully edited one question, this is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784757/unable-to-run-new-project-after-updating-the-eclipse-and-adtold-proj-are-runnin

It is showing that I have edited the question, but I haven't received any reputation points for it. What is the reason for not getting reputation points for successful editing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

User called `Java` edited the code sample, see [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/175885).

By retagging the question, you actually Approved his suggested edit and added your own edit, which was the tags edit.

When you'll have 2K+ rep you'll see it's called "Improve". :)

Another option for what happened is that you really edited the code adding formatting plus edited the tags, but the other user also edited the code and the two edits were merged.

Comment: yes, I think this is the reason.

Comment: Wait, so people with only the `retag` privilege can `improve` and therefor accept suggested edits!? That sounds wrong...

Comment: @Bobby well, retag performs full edit behind the scenes but allows only tags edit - so yes, sounds like we stumbled over hidden feature/bug - you name it. As the senior among the two of us, will you report this on separate discussion? :-)

Comment: Woah woah woah...slow down there buddy..."senior"...now I feel...odd. ;) [Well, I did...thanks for asking.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118367/do-retags-from-2k-rep-users-really-improve-pending-suggested-edits) :)

Comment: @Bobby lol! Nicely done, you got my vote. :)

Answer (score 4):

You have enough reputation to [retag questions](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions). Retags do not go through an approval process and therefore do not earn you any additional reputation. Only edit suggestions that change content along with tags will earn you reputation when approved.

Comment: but I had also edited code sample.

Comment: @Arjun: If you did, I'm not seeing it. I only see "edited tags" with your name in the question's revision history: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8784757/revisions Or did you link to the wrong question?

Comment: ok, I saw the editing history, there was another user, who also edited code sample, so I think he saved first that's why it is not showing in my editing history.

Comment: In that case, looks like Shadow Wizard got it right.