# Do retags from <2k rep users really "improve" pending suggested edits?

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

As [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard) pointed out on [his answer to another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118362/136489), it seems like a <2k rep user was able to [improve a suggested edit by simply retaging the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8784757/revisions). The [suggested edit shows up as accepted by Community](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/175885) and has the same timestamp as the retag.

As we all know, only people with edit privileges should be allowed to approve/improve/reject suggested edits...but it seems like retags from <2k rep users do improve suggested edits.

Comment: Note that OP can also "approve" suggested edit without knowing about it. [example](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8788088/revisions) (see second and third revisions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there were a few little glitches there.

1. If you clicked "retag" and in the mean time somebody already submitted a suggested edit, we showed you a 404. (changed it to display a simple message)
2. If you got to the retag screen, then someone submitted an edit and finally you did your retag, you would push the edit through. (fixed)