# Suggested Edit overwritten by OP edit

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits

I found this [meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118359/182513), but I am not sure if this is the same issue.

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11759042/250725), I did some reformatting of the indentation in the code block to make it a bit more readable and it was [submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/186769) for peer review. A few minutes later, it appears the OP made an edit that added some additional code. It looks like my suggested edit was applied when the OP saved his/her edit, and it looks like he got the "credit" for the edit.

I'm not really concerned about the 2 rep points; I'm more curious why this happened and if this is a bug (or limitation) in the editing feature, or if this is known/intended behavior?

Note that this is not a suggested edit that's overridden by a concurrent edit: the recorded edit starts from the post-suggested edit state (and in fact can be identical to it, as in [this](https://patents.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/48) [case](https://patents.stackexchange.com/posts/133/revisions)).

Comment: @DavidFullerton This doesn't look like it's behaving as it should. Since the OP's edit started from psubsee2003's version (and even kept everything from it including the edit summary), the suggested edit should be recorded as improved, not rejected. This isn't an isolated case ([here](http://patents.stackexchange.com/posts/133/revisions)'s another example, [this](http://patents.stackexchange.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/48) is the suggested edit).

Comment: @DavidFullerton just following up a year later here since I wasn't experienced enough at the time to question it.  Can you confirm this is indeed by design?  It looks like the OP's edit treated the suggested edit as if he clicked "Improve" but unchecked "this edit was helpful" without any sign that they actually performed that action.  If the OP did indeed review the post and unchecked it, shouldn't they at least be shown in the suggested edit review page?

Answer (score 11):

Your suggested edit wasn't overwritten, it [was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/337152).

As there is no user who actively rejected it it probably means that the following happened:

1. OP clicked edit at some point, prior to 12:29
2. You submitted the edit suggestion at 12:29, the OP was still editing the post.
3. OP submitted his edit at 12:33 and the system merged the edits, auto rejecting the suggestion either due to a bug or by design, if "reject" is the default action of improving suggested edit.

Note the rejection happened in exactly the same time of the OP edit:

> [image]

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying it.  That does make more sense as to what happened.

Comment: This is what happened, but it doesn't make sense. The default action of improving suggested edits is approval. Since the OP started from the suggested edit text (even reused the edit summary), the suggested edit should be marked as approved (or improved, which is now indicated differently).

Comment: @Gilles good point, hopefully David will check the code and give official reply.

Comment: @Gilles note I did say "more sense", not necessarily complete sense :-)

Answer (score 3):

The post is not locked if it is edited. So it is possible that two or more users are editing at the same time.

However, there is some intelligence behind this to preserve the most 'heavy' edit. But still these circumstances happen.

If you get  the message that the post is already edited, copy the post (containing your edits) and paste it in a text editor so you have your edits at hand. Try to edit the post again (do not paste all text else you lose the others edits).

If your edits were good, big chance they are already committed.

Comment: I did not see the new edit notification popup, and there was about a 2-3 minute delay between when I submitted my suggestion and when the "this question has been edited" notification popped up.

Comment: And my changes were actually committed as part of the OP edit (looking at the edit history, it shows the changes I submitted as part of the OP edit).  So either the OP did it himself (with virtually the same spacing) and overwrote mine (which I do not think is the case, given the code he added has the same indentation issues as the previous code I tried to cleaning), or when the OP committed his edit, mine were applied at the same time.