# Who keeps a check on the Community user?

Tags: discussion, community-user

I know that the Community user is not an actual user, and it keeps the site clean. I just wanted to know if there is someone who keeps a check on the actions of the Community user.

Will the rejected edits be manually checked by someone?

Comment: Your [suggested edit here](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/337218) got stomped on by an edit by the original poster of the question.  Yours is *a lot* better though, so please resubmit it so this injustice can be righted.  (Also, get rid of "Hi", "please help me" and capitalize "Android" if you would.  Thanks!)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Community is no human; things are assigned automatically to Community under certain circumstances, as a result of voting and other actions by actual humans.

Those humans and their actions are accountable, no need to check Community for any irregularities here.

In other words, your edit was rejected by a human, and in this case the human probably clicked the 'Improve' button and marked your edit as 'not helpful'. Another possibility is that there was a conflicting edit that invalidated yours, resulting in an automatic reject.

See [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

Comment: If [this is the specific case](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/337218) then the edit most likely clashed [with the one of the OP](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11759991/revisions) at that same time.

Comment: @Bart: right, I just found the same suggested edit; updated the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Such rejection can happen for two reasons I know of:

1. User manually click "Improve" or "Edit" button when reviewing the suggested edit then untick the "this edit was helpful" checkbox.
2. Other edit was made to the post and got merged with your suggestion, causing auto rejection. See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141867/suggested-edit-overwritten-by-op-edit) for a good example.