# Access denied for edit posts

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I have a problem with my Stack Overflow account. My edit access was disabled for all posts. I saw some similar questions related to my problem, which explained some of the reasons why this might happen. So I waited for 5 days but it wasn't resolved. My questions therefore are

- How can I get back my privilege to edit posts?
- What is the exact reason for this problem?
- How can I see my edited posts?

Comment: It seems that too many of your suggested edits were rejected. So an automatic ban kicked in. You'll need to wait it out.

Comment: How can i see the status....? Can u please suggest me what i have to do for this..?

Comment: Go to your profile -> activity -> suggestions. Then you can a list of all your suggestions what became of them.

Comment: Five days is too little. In my experience about a year ago, suggestions ban was about two weeks. **Possible Duplicate:** [Is there a penalty for one's edit suggestion being rejected?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78129/is-there-a-penalty-for-ones-edit-suggestion-being-rejected), [Why is the edit button disabled?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled), [Account is Not Allowed to Suggest Edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140936/account-is-not-allowed-to-suggest-edits)

Comment: @Mysticial thanks for your help.... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're banned from having too many suggested edits rejected, the ban is 7 days. See [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

It's unfortunate that you had to be temporarily banned in order to get feedback. [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor) You can check the outcome of your edit suggestions [in the activity tab in your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1629481/basith?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) but it's annoyingly difficult.

Looking through your suggested edit history, these were rejected:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/596748 Your suggested edit was [overwritten by an edit by the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141867/suggested-edit-overwritten-by-op-edit).
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/596700 Your suggested edit was overwritten by someone else editing the post.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/602222 Where on earth did this code you inserted come from? Your meager attempt at fixing the English isn't useful.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/603196 Your suggested edit was overwritten by someone else editing the post.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/605635 This is what you should have done in your first suggested edit on that post (https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/605633). Your second suggested edit was overwritten by someone else editing the post.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/606470 You changed a typo in the code in the question. That typo was one of the problems that the asker faced. Never change the code in questions, except to fix the indentation (and not even that in languages that are sensitive to indentation, obviously).

These were approved, but you could (and should) have done a better job:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/596698 You should have removed the “enter code here” junk, and you broke the formatting of several arrays below. I would have rejected this edit as too minor. There are other less important things you should have done: fix English issues such as capitalization, remove the “please help me” fluff at the end.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/591172 Ok, but you should have capitalized “I” and other English corrections.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/591032 Ok, but again improving the English would have been nice.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/590825 This is an invalid edit which should not have been approved. Don't use code markup for proper names, use code markup for what you type as input to a program (code, file names, etc.). There were [things to improve](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12273745/3) about this post, but not what you did.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/603193 Another invalid edit that should not have been approved.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/603318 Ok, but again improving the English would have been nice.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/605633 This edit was approved, but you should had done a better job: also remove the empty lines.

They were mostly rejected because someone else made an edit that overrode yours. [These rejections should not count for the automatic ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137611/suggested-edit-rejections-for-concurrent-edits-should-not-count-for-the-suggeste).

However, you did make some bad suggestions that were approved. (If you are one of the approvers and you read this: please do a better job, don't blindly click “approve”!) Please follow my advice when you return to suggesting edits in a couple of days. When fixing broken formatting, go all the way, don't leave the code in a half-formatted state. Don't use code markup for things that aren't code. Remove “fluff” such as “Hi sir I have a doubt: Here is my question: ” and “thanks in advanced” and “plzsendtehcodez”. Even if English isn't your native language so you can't completely fix the English, at least do a few simple things that make the text more readable, such as capitalizing the first letter of a sentence and the word “I”.