# Edit suggestion overwrote edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I have improved a first post and have seen while reviewing there is an edit suggestion.
In general I have skipped the vote for it.

Looking some moments later at the post, it is edited by several peoples without any "real" changes https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21598568/revisions.

I think the issue is very similar to [Suggested Edit overwritten by OP edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141867/suggested-edit-overwritten-by-op-edit), but in my opinion it would be better if there is the possibility to see that there is already an edit done or similar.

This behavior could destroy an improved post by someone else.

Comment: Nope -- the last person edited the suggested version and made minor changes as part of the review queue (once you get 2000 rep you can review suggested edits and there is an option to "improve and reject/approve").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, this not the same behavior as the question you cited.

In the linked question, 2 edits, 1 suggested edit by a user with less than 2K (at the time) and 1 by the OP, were merged together and there was no record of the suggested edit in the revision history because the suggested edit was automatically rejected when it was merged into the OP's edit.

In this case, your edit is there, as are 2 more edits.

First your edit was submitted at 9:44 UTC

> [image]

The first approval on the following suggested edit occured at 9:46 UTC, suggesting that the edit was submitted a minute or so after yours

> [image]

Additionally, revision 3 of that post used your edit as a base, so the editor there definitely did not even click the edit button until after your edit.  Revision 4 of the post came up during the approval process because one of the approvers of that suggested edit saw something else that need fixed.

I see no evidence that your edit was being destroyed in any way, only users that continued to edit because they thought your edit was missing something.

Based on your comments, you seem to be concerned that a [suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) will overwrite a regular edit when submitted at roughly the same time.  Fortunately, that isn't possible.  As a 2K user, your edit will always take priority.

Consider the following 2 scenarios.

**Scenario 1**

1. You start to edit a post
2. A <2K user starts to edit the same post
3. The <2K users submits his edit
4. You submit your edit before the suggested edit is approved.
5. The suggested edit is [immediately rejected by Community ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184993/182513) and your edit is used

**Scenario 2**

1. You start to edit a post
2. A <2K user starts to edit the same post
3. You submit your edit.
4. The <2K users tries submits his edit but is prevented from doing so as your edit is the current revision.  The user trying to submit the suggested will get an error message explaining that they can't submit the edit.

And in both of the above scenarios the order of #1 and #2 could be reversed, it is the order of steps 3-5 that determine what happens, but in the end, your edit will always be the current revision.

In fact the only time where 2 users are editing the revision of the same post will result in the 2nd edit winning the edit race is when the 2nd edit is [considered more substantial based on character count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93169/the-editing-race-the-slackers-always-win) (not the best way to decide this, but it is how it is done now) and is **not** a suggested edit (suggested edits will never win an edit race unless they get approved before you submit yours and yours is considered less substantial).

Comment: Okay perhaps is destroyed the wrong term. The edit is overwritten by another edit (suggestion). That is my point.

Comment: @CSchulz I still don't understand what the issue is.  Are you saying that once you edit, no one else should be able to edit it again?

Comment: I have seen revision 3 a little bit different as it was. I thought it based on revision 1 and so my conclusion was it overwrote my revision (2).

Comment: @CSchulz regular edits will always trump suggested edits.  So it is impossible for someone to suggest an edit that uses an older revision, so there shouldn't be a concern of that happening..  I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks. :) Could you please add a source where to read these workflows?

Comment: @CSchulz I'll have to look for them, I don't have the sources handy, I just know how it works through experience and spending too much time on meta.

Comment: @CSchulz couldn't find a [meta-tag:faq] source for everything, but I linked a few things that are probably helpful.  But trust me, I'm right :)