# Strange Edit behavior

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I suggested an edit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17571841/1324019) and noticed some strange behavior. The title was originally "Visual studio 2005 Split coma separated values", I removed the "Visual Studio 2005" part, and made no other changes to the post.

However, someone else had edited the post (making more significant changes) in between the time I began editing and the time I finished editing. [Revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17571841/revisions) (#4 is the one that happened in between my edit).

As a result, when I submitted my edit, it compared the text I was submitting to the text of the new edit, making it look as though I wanted to revert the post to its previous (and deficient) state, when in fact all I wanted to do was change the title. [The edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2480275) was rejected, of course.

On the surface I suppose this behavior makes sense. But I'm surprised that there wasn't at least some kind of prompt like "an edit has been made to this post, load revised version" prior to me submitting my edit.

Comment: that's happened to the best of us, you'll be 2000 rep soon enough and this won't be a problem

Comment: @Yve Indeed, it seems like this would happen frequently. But I think it merits something being done about it, a prompt at very least would be helpful and probably not too much work.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141252/lock-a-post-for-editing-or-at-least-display-a-warning

Comment: @mansfield, yes I was often tempted to post about this, I just whinge too much on the site, so decided not too :) And that is NOT a go at you at all, making fun of myself... good question, I just think I know the answer you're going to get ;)

Comment: This was typical race condition. Happens. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118359/no-reputation-awarded-for-a-suggested-edit for related issue.